# Swift Sets creating a visual of them and searching through them

Tags: swift, set

I have looked on google and wasn't able to find a library that would allow me to create an image of all the sets. I was wondering if anyone new if such a library existed.

My second question is that at the moment I am doing

```
// create sets
var set1: Set = [2, 3, 5, 7]
var set2: Set = [2, 3, 4, 6]
var set3: Set = [1, 3, 8, 7]

var new: Set = [2,3]
var finally = [String]()

if(new.isSubset(of:set1)
{
     finally.append("set1")
}

if(new.isSubset(of:set2)
{
     finally.append("set2")
}


if(new.isSubset(of:set3)
{
     finally.append("set3")
}
```

print(finally)

this is a horrible way of doing it and have been working on a function that automates this process. I tried to create a list of sets:

```
   var foo = [set1,set2,set3]
```

the issue with that is that I lose the name of the sets since the output is

```
[{5,7,2,3},{6,2,4,3},{7,3,1,8}]
```

therefore I decided to create a dictionary:

```
 var baz = [ 'a': set1,
             'b': set2,
             'c': set3]
 //for loop through dictionary 
 var finally2 = [String]()
 for(key,value) in baz {
     if(newset.isSubset(of: value))
     {
         finally2.append(key)
     }
   }
   print(finally2)
```

I don't like my final dictionary solution and was wondering if there was a better solution just using sets.

Comment: How about an array of tuples? So you'd have `var sets = [(name: "set1", set: set1), (name: "set2", set: set2)]` and you'd iterate through tuples like `for set in sets` and you can access the name as `set.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using array and exploiting the fact that array elements has an order, if you insist of using sets you can use the same solution with `NSOrderedSet` because sets does not have an order.

```
var set1: Set = [2, 3, 5, 7]
var set2: Set = [2, 3, 4, 6]
var set3: Set = [1, 3, 8, 7]
var new: Set = [2,3]

//let or:NSOrderedSet = [set1, set2, set3] // NSOrderedSet
let ArrayOfSets: Array = [set1, set2, set3]
let finalArry: [String] = ArrayOfSets.flatMap {
    if new.isSubset(of: $0) {
        let i = ArrayOfSets.index(of: $0)
        return "Set\(String(describing: i!+1))"
    }
    return ""
    }.filter{ $0 != ""}

print(finalArry) //["Set1", "Set2"]
```

You can do the same with for loop of course